# "ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table '<table_name>' was not locked with LOCK TABLES" error because of a trigger

Tags: mysql, docker, triggers, innodb

I have a table (`my_table`) on a schema (`db1`) that I am trying to migrate to another schema (`db2`) on the same server. To do so I have created a trigger on `db1` on insert, update and delete to `my_table` that essentially copies the operations to `db2.my_table`. Everything works well in dev, but we have a weird setup where both those schemas are on different docker images for migration purposes. So `db1` is on one container and `db2` is on another container, two different mysql server instances.

This causes problem with the replication triggers locally, so I've added an `IF` clause in them to make sure `db2` exists on the server before firing. Here is the `AFTER INSERT` trigger for example :

```sql
create trigger insert_my_table
    after INSERT
    on db1.my_table
    for each row
begin
    IF
        (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT SCHEMA_NAME
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
                       WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'db2')) THEN
        insert into db2.my_table
        select *
        from db1.my_table ff
        where ff.id = NEW.id
        on duplicate key update db2.my_table.id=NEW.id;
    END IF;
end;
```

Now I can insert new rows in `my_table` locally without problem. But if I try to lock the table before inserting (which `mysqldump` does for example) :

```sql
lock tables `my_table` write;


insert into my_table (id, name, description) value (1, 'test', 'test_desc');
```

then I get this error

`"ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'my_table' was not locked with LOCK TABLES"`

What gives? Is there something I'm forgetting ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that once you lock any table in the session, the session can only access the tables that have been explicitly locked for it. Since you are writing to `my_table` in `db2` you will have to lock it as well.

MySQL [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Importantly:

> A session that requires locks must acquire all the locks that it needs
> in a single LOCK TABLES statement. While the locks thus obtained are
> held, the session can access only the locked tables. For example, in
> the following sequence of statements, an error occurs for the attempt
> to access t2 because it was not locked in the LOCK TABLES statement:
>
> ```sql
> mysql> LOCK TABLES t1 READ;
> mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1;
> +----------+
> | COUNT(*) |
> +----------+
> |        3 |
> +----------+
> mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2;
> ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 't2' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
> ```
>
> Tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database are an exception. They can
> be accessed without being locked explicitly even while a session holds
> table locks obtained with LOCK TABLES.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem here is that locally, on the container my trigger is on, the `db2` schema doesn't exist, so I can't lock `db2.my_table`... Is that a weird loophole where the trigger only mentions a table that doesn't exist, but since it's not (and could not be) locked, I get the error anyway? It seems weird to me.

Comment: Huh, sorry, I apparently glossed over that part. I don't know how LOCK TABLES is implemented, but I suspect you are correct.

In this scenario, if they are on separate servers, I guess my question then is how does mysql server A containing `db1` know anything about the `db2` schema contained on mysql server B? Are they [federated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) somehow?

Comment: In our other environments (dev/preprod/prod), both schemas are on the same server, but our services still open a connection for each schema it wants to access.  In this case, locally, we would open a connection for each corresponding container that has the schema we want to access. In other environment, we would open a connection to the same server on different schemas (using jdbc driver for example).

Comment: That makes sense for the services/applications: they open a connection to each database as needed, the databases don't need to know about each other. But when the trigger fires it isn't using that connection; all of its machinations are internal to the mysql server that hosts the schema with the table that has that trigger defined.